# asp.net div/iframe as target

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a div with called `mainContent` and if I click a link I want to clear `maincontent`, add an `iframe` to the div, and open up the page from the link in the `iframe`

How to go about doing that?
I assume some JS is needeD?

Comment: why don't you use the power of jquery rather than the good old javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="javascript:SetContent();">Some link</a>
<script>
    function SetContent()
    {
       document.getElementById('mainContent').innerHTML = 
          "<iframe width=" + screen.width + "px height=" + screen.height +  
          "px src='http://www.SomeUrl.com'></iframe>";
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Perfect. It's exactly it. Is there a way to create the iframe with the width/height of the current resolution?

Comment: Yes you can access the resolution using `screen.width` and `screen.height`

Comment: One last question, say I want to add the value of a textbox as a parameter to `SetContent()` how to call the textbox.Text value inside the `<a href="javascript:SetContent();">Some link</a> 
`?

Comment: `<a href="javascript:SetContent(document.getElementById('TextBoxId').value);">Some link</a>`

Comment: Any idea why the content in the iframe is smaller than if you open it in a new page? Can that be set to be the same size as usual?

Answer (score 0):

Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tvJah/)?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addiframe(){
    document.getElementById("maincontent").innerHTML='<iframe name="myiframe"></iframe>';
}​
</script>
<div id="maincontent">asd</div>
<a href="//example.com" onclick="addiframe()" target="myiframe">click</a>​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet. you need to include jquery library for using this.

```
function appendContent(){
$('#mainContent').html('');
$('#mainContent').html('<iframe name="myiframe" width=620 height=380 src="http://stackoverflow.com" frameborder="1"></iframe>');
}
```